# Firefox 6 JavaScript gotchas

Tags: javascript, firefox

What sort of backward compatibility issues could I have?

Is there a standard place to look for such issues, like on the mozilla website?

Thanks.

Comment: Or explain to me why this question ought to be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, take a look at the [Firefox 6 for Developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_6_for_developers) article on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

(While you're at it, you may also want to look at [Firefox 7 for Developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_7_for_developers).)

Hope this helps!